# Sorting a list with Collator in Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

Assume I have a list of names with polish diacritics signs:

```kotlin
listOf("Zosia", "Łucja", "Asia")
```

I want to sort it and achieve the result like:

```kotlin
[Asia, Łucja, Zosia]
```

I can perform it with Collator in kotlin like this:

```kotlin
listOf.sortedWith { s1, s2 ->
        Collator.getInstance(Locale("pl", "PL")).compare(s1, s2)
    }
```

Unfortunately, I cannot use the above code in commonMain module, because the `Collator` and `Locale` class is unreachable there.
So I decided to create expect/actual functions but I don't know how to implement it for the iOS version.

In Swift I could write:

```swift
listOf.sorted { $0.localizedCompare($1) == .orderedAscending }
```

but it's not helpful for kotlin implementation in iosMain module.

So, how to sort a list with Collator for iOS in KMM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `iosMain` you can use `localizedCompare` it is method of `NSString` class. You just need to import it from `platform.Foundation`

```kotlin
import platform.Foundation.NSString
import platform.Foundation.localizedCompare

fun List<String>.sortedLocaleAware(): List<String> {
    return sortedWith { s1, s2 ->
        (s1 as NSString).localizedCompare(s2).toInt()
    }
}
```

You'll get compiler warning because of cast to `NSString` it will tell you that this cast never succeeds. But that's OK, it's recommended way [from Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-objc-interop.html#casting-between-mapped-types).

You can suppress it with `@Suppress("CAST_NEVER_SUCCEEDS")`